# Search, Increment, Replace and Save to New Files

Tags: powershell

I'm new to Powershell.

Let's say I have a file named **Grocery_01.txt**

And in this text file, there are several texts like;

*Apple.1.Green*

I want to change these texts to >> *Apple.2.Green*

And save it to a new txt file named **Grocery_02.txt**

Then, I want to repeat the process until I have a total of 99 files, with the last file named **Grocery_99.txt** which includes *Apple.99.Green*

Comment: Sounds like a neat project, good luck!

Comment: Your question itself is not clear. Apple.2.Green is also on the same file? At least, provide a sample data of your main file.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your help. I want to create as many files as I want by increasing the numbers I choose in the content. I must select the number by it's unique structure. In this case ".1." If the first file contains Apple.1.Green and Banana.1.Red. The 25th file should contain Apple.25.Green and Banana.25.Red.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample for you. Assuming that your Grocery_01 file looks like

```
Apple.1.Green
Apple.2.Green
Banana.1.Red
Apple.10.Green
```

```
$apples = Get-Content C:\PS\Grocery_01.txt | Select-String -Pattern "Apple"
foreach ($line in $apples) {

$number = $line -replace '\D' #to get number from string

New-Item "C:\PS\Grocery_$number.txt" #create new file with the new number
Add-Content -Path "C:\PS\Grocery_$number.txt" -value $line

}
```

You may try this code and see if it suits your output.

> 

**Answer2:**
In this case, I will use a CSV file for input and ForEach-Object to process each line.

```
Import-Csv C:\temp\grocerylist.csv | ForEach-Object {
    for ($i = 1; $i -le $($_.Count); $i++) {

        if (-not (Test-Path "C:\Temp\test\Grocery_$i.txt")) {
            New-Item "C:\Temp\test\Grocery_$i.txt"
            Add-Content  -Path "C:\temp\test\Grocery_$i.txt" -Value "$($_.FruitName).$i.$($_.Colour)" 

        }
        else {
            Add-Content  -Path "C:\temp\test\Grocery_$i.txt" -Value "$($_.FruitName).$i.$($_.Colour)"
        }
    }
}
```

And my CSV file will look like below(each heading in a different Column):

```
FruitName Count Colour
Apple     99    Green
Banana    25    Red
```

Note: Before you raise a question, please provide the details about what have you done so far. That will help you to get quick answers.

Comment: It seems this code takes the number and line from each "apple" it spots and creates a new file.

Comment: I have an updated in section Answer2

Comment: I have an updated in section Answer2